# Flutter: Perform Action On Application Exit

Tags: flutter

Where should you put code that needs to run on application exit?

I tried to override the `dispose()` method of my main window state. But it doesn't seem to get called when I terminate the app from Android Studio (not sure if it gets called on a real phone when the OS terminates the app).

Comment: for which OS? android or iOS?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya ideally platform-agnostic

Comment: check [here](https://medium.com/pharos-production/flutter-app-lifecycle-4b0ab4a4211a)